# Function naming: select vs find vs get

Tags: design-patterns, naming

I sometimes wandering when i name function 'get' method.

for example,

```
- getFileInfo();
- selectFileInfo();
- findFileInfo();
```

It seems very similar to me.

Is there any patterns or best practices?

Comment: I think it is not standardized. To my understanding of English, I would imagine `getFoo()` is just to return a reference. The information is already there, you just need to pick it. `selectFoo()` sounds like a decision involved. It base on something to process and return the value according to the input. I interpret `findFoo()` as there is a database query behind, or a iteration walk through a data structure to find the specific object for you.

Comment: That sounds promising to me. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182113/how-and-why-to-decide-between-naming-methods-with-get-and-find-prefixes